# http://localhost/phpmyadmin/index.php "No input file specified." nginx Windows Server 2012 php 7

Tags: nginx

I am trying to setup the nginx server at **Windows Server 2012**. The problem that I am facing: When I try to access or http://localhost/phpmyadmin/index.php or http://localhost/test.php I receive the message "No input file specified." at nginx Windows Server 2012 php 7. The netstat -abn has the port 9000 open and listening :

- TCP    127.0.0.1:9000         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  [php-cgi.exe]
- TCP    0.0.0.0:80             0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  [nginx.exe]
- TCP    0.0.0.0:3306           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  [mysqld.exe]

The nginx folder is `C:\nginx` and inside there is `C:\nginx\html` & `C:\nginx\html\phpmyadmin`  and `c:\nginx\php\`     folders with all necessary files.

nginx.conf:

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            root   /nginx/html;
            index  index.php index.html index.htm;
        }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

        # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
        #}

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000



        location ~ .php$ {
            root            html;
            include fastcgi.conf;
            fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index   index.php;
            fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME html/$fastcgi_script_name;
            include         fastcgi_params;

        }       

        location /phpmyadmin {
            root            html/phpmyadmin/index.php;
            include fastcgi.conf;
            fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
            index index.php;
        }   

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        location ~ /\.ht {
            deny  all;
        }


}
    # another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       8000;
    #    listen       somename:8080;
    #    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}


    # HTTPS server
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       443 ssl;
    #    server_name  localhost;

    #    ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
    #    ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

    #    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
    #    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    #    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    #    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}

}
```

Please can anyone help me? What do I need to change to the conf or ini files or what else is wrong with my setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple problems with your configuration.

You have a common document root, so you should place one `root` directive in the `server` block which is then inherited by all location blocks.

The "No input file specified" error message means that `SCRIPT_FILENAME` is missing or wrong.

The `location /phpmyadmin` block is unnecessary and should be removed.

In summary, try this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name  localhost;

    root   /nginx/html;

    location / {
        index  index.php index.html index.htm;     
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include         fastcgi.conf;
        include         fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }       

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny  all;
    }
}
```

A useful resource for `nginx` [documentation is here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/).